# High school AP calculus help

Tags: calculus

[image]How do we solve this problem?

$$ \int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\, dx$$

All I know is that i need to get the bottom part to equal $\sin^{-1} x$.

Comment: A $u$-substitution will suffice. Let $u=1-x^2$.

Comment: I have tried it but i get -2 over root U du

Comment: Write the indefinite integral as   ${-1\over2}\int u^{-1/2}\,du$.

Comment: If you really want to, you can let $x=\sin t$. Then $dx=\cos t\,dt$.

Comment: Is there a way to use 1/ sqrt 1-x^2 dx in to sin -1 x ?

Comment: @chrissykwon: Look at your sixth line; you've left out a negative sign. So that should be a $-\frac{1}{2}$ to the left of your margin. Now look at the seventh line; what would happen if you differentiated $-\frac{1}{2}u^{1/2}$? You wouldn't end up with $u^{-1/2}$. (This, by the way, is a way to make sure you've integrated correctly: Differentiate your answer and see if you get your question back.) Fix those two spots and let me know what you get.

Comment: YAY i got the answer, i did the integration wrong. THANK YOU so much for your time and help, this sight and you guys are the best for providing help for everyone who need it :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $u = 1 - x^2$, then $du = -2x dx \iff \frac{1}{2}du = x dx$. We can put the limits of integration aside for a moment and rewrite the integral as

$$-\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{du}{\sqrt u} = -\frac{1}{2}\int u^{-1/2} du$$

This integral probably looks like something you know how to handle.  So — find the antiderivative and substitute $1 - x^2$ back in wherever you see $u$.  Then you can plug in your original limits of integration for the answer.

What do you get?

Comment: thank you for your hep !:)

Comment: the answer says im supposed to get 2- root3 over 2

Comment: @chrissykwon: Hopefully, that answer's right! What did *you* get? :) Were you able to find the antiderivative? My book calls what you'd use the general power rule.

Comment: Hello, I keep getting (2- root2) over 8 :(

Comment: @chrissykwon: If you post an addendum to your question, I'll try to figure out what happened.  Please include what you got for the antiderivative using the $u$-substitution.

Comment: I've added a picture, do you mind telling me where I might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$
\int_0^{1/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\Big( x\,dx \Big).
$$
This should hint at what substitution you should use.  If you don't understand this kind of hint, then that's the main thing you need to learn about integration by substitution.